# How to properly use a MySQLi function in post method Login this is how i do it. but has an error

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

connection.php

```
<?php
$host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$pass = "mikred###";
$db = "itsupportdb";

$mysqli = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $db);
if(mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    printf("Connection Failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}
?>
```

glbLoginFunct.php

```
<?php
        include("connection.php");  
        class Functions {

            public static function __Login()
            {           
                session_start();

                if(isset($_POST['btnLogin']))
                {           
                    $id = $_POST['user'];
                    $pass = $_POST['pass'];

                    $query = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM syslogin WHERE username=? AND password=? LIMIT 1");
                    $query->bind_param('ss', $id, $pass);
                    $query->execute();
                    $query->bind_result($id, $pass);
                    $row = $query->fetch();
                    if($row == true) 
                    {
                        $_SESSION['LogID'] = 1;
                        $_SESSION['ProfID'] = 2;
                        header('Location: test.php');
                        exit();
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        ?><script type="text/javascript"> alert('ERROR!'); </script><?php
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    ?>
```

mainLogin.php

```
<?php require("includes/glbLoginFunct.php"); ?>
<form action="<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>" method="POST">
<fieldset>
    <legend>LOGIN FORM:</legend>
    <label id="user">Username: <input type="text" name="user" maxlenght="10"/></label><br />
    <label id="pass">Password: <input type="password" name="pass" maxlenght="7"/></label><br />
    <label id="buttons"><input type="submit" class="imgBtn" name="btnLogin" value="Login User"/></label><br />              
    <a href="index.php?link=Forgot">Forgot Password</a>
</fieldset>
</form>
<?php Functions::__Login() ?>
```

why does it say:

Notice: Undefined variable: mysqli in ...\includes\glbLoginFunct.php on line 14

Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in ...\includes\glbLoginFunct.php on line 14

Comment: There's a lot wrong with your setup; for one, you are calling JS code within a PHP class declaration. For two, you are calling a global variable within a class. That's just trouble around the corner, man.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either make `$mysqli` a parameter of the function, or put:

```
global $mysqli;
```

at the beginning of the `__Login` function.

BTW, you shouldn't use that name for your function. From the documentation of [Magic Methods](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php):

> *Caution*: PHP reserves all function names starting with __ as magical. It is recommended that you do not use function names with __ in PHP unless you want some documented magic functionality.